# Relaxation process in semiconductors

Tags: semiconductor-physics, spectroscopy, non-linear-optics

I was reading some papers on pump-probe spectroscopy of silicon. In this spectroscopy, pump pulse excites carriers(electrons and holes) from valance to conduction band and probe pulse with various time delays gives information on various relaxation process happening in the sample. My question is that what exactly are **electron momentum relaxation** and **electron-phonon energy relaxation** processes?

I am not sure, but I guess unless electrons are excited, they don't interact with anything. But after excitation when electrons move to conduction band, they can interact among themselves hence giving rise to carrier-carrier scattering process and they might interact with the lattice and give rise to carrier-phonon scattering process. 
Carrier-carrier scattering might be related to momentum relaxation process and carrier-phonon scattering might be related to energy relaxation process.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Think of what electrons in the conduction band can interact with to cause 'relaxation', and what 'relaxation' really represents.

Comment: Is it reasonable to say that after relaxation time, all interactions have died out and carriers have returned to valence band?

Comment: A 'standard' relaxation process goes as $e^{-t/\tau}$, so no your comment does not apply.

Comment: I searched about my question, finally I found an image describing momentum relaxation process. Electrons moving towards minima of conduction band is the momentum relaxation process. But now what is the energy relaxation process?
   https://image.slidesharecdn.com/opticalspectroscopy2-160108125138/95/optical-spectroscopy-12-638.jpg?cb=1452257585